# How can I login again when I logout using Google Plus Auth

Tags: django, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

To login with Google Plus Auth, I use the example of Python Social Auth at https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/tree/master/examples/django_example

And I have the scenario as follows:

Firstly, I login by google plus sign in button

```
<div id="signinButton">
   <span class="g-signin" data-scope="{{ plus_scope }}"
                       data-clientid="{{ plus_id }}"
                       data-redirecturi="postmessage"
                       data-accesstype="offline"
                       data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
                       data-callback="signInCallback">
   </span>
</div>
```

Secondly, I click on the logout button to sign out

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/logout/">
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
      Logout
    </a>
```

Finally, when I login again by Google Plus sign button, the Google popup can not display to enter the username and password. However, I can login again by the button of Django example

```
   <a class="col-md-2 btn btn-default" name="{{ backend|backend_class }}" href="{% url "social:begin" backend=name %}">
      <i class="fa fa-{{ name|icon_name }}"></i>
      {{ backend|backend_name }}
   </a>
```

But I don't like this method because this is not recommended from Google https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/redirect-uri-flow

As I understand, Google popup cannot display because I logged in by Google. I just logout from my django example app. For that reason, the popup cannot open.

However, I think this is a common action of users. They can login/logout many times from our Django apps and they don't need to know about their Google status.

So, is there any approach to login again for my scenario?

Thank you so much

Notes: This is my [screen shot](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4p9CYXQkkrxVGZySnpSaXE1NVE/edit)

Comment: wait .. what approach you want.? If the user willing to logout then you are gonna log the user forcefully using google credential ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Please explain more detail. Please see my screen shot. I just use the Django example. There is two buttons such as "Google Plus Sign in" button and "Logout" button of Django Example. When I click on "Logout", basically I think I can login again by "Google Plus Sign in". So, is there any way to login again for my scenario? Thank you

Comment: It seems that you want that a logout from the app also implies a logout from Google, for that you need something lieke a Google JS library and call the required function to trigger a logout action when clicking the Logout button.